# integer doesn't update

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

hi i have the follow code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  int myValue;


     protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        myValue = myValue + 1;
        Label2.Text = myValue.ToString();

    }

}
```

I can't seems to increase the value, the outcome will always be 1.....

Comment: replace int myValue with static int myValue;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the new page class gets created every time post back happens (due to button click). So state held by instance variables will be lost between requests. You need to use view-state to preserve state. For example,

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   private int myValue
{
    get
    {
      var value = ViewState["myValue"];
      return null == value ? 0: (int)value;
    }
    set
    {
       ViewState["myValue"] = value;
    }
}


     protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        myValue = myValue + 1;
        Label2.Text = myValue.ToString();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The class instance is re-created on GET/POST request, so either make this variable in `ViewState`, or in static variable if its purpose is application wide.

```
ViewState["Num"] = myValue;
```

and on button click event, use this.

```
myValue = ViewState["Num"] as int;
myValue = myValue + 1;
Label2.Text = myValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Wouldn't you get a compiler error on calling 'ViewState["Num"] as int'? As could be applied to nullable and reference types only.